# Lost key bindings for Up, Down, Left and Right keys after sudoing to another user / another server via xterm

Tags: linux, binding, terminal, xterm, stty

[image]I know I messed with this long ago  but my stty settings will not work when I  sudo & ssh   to another user and server.
on server #1 I am myself and history  can be invoked using U / D keys ,navigated using the L / R keys and edited using backspace.See screenshot
I then sudo and ssh to another server and everything is lost. U / D  will not pull up history and neither will L / R navigate the cursor across the history.

```
stty
speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
erase = ^H; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?;
-brkint ixany
-echok -echoctl -echoke
```

the stty o/p on server # 1  and # 2 are the very same.  as above. Why this different behavior . How can I fix this so I can invoke history w/ U/D and L / R navigate the cursor across the history and backspace to begin editing it

Used Xterm to connect

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas;

- check the TERM settings are the same
- use stty -g to save your stty settings and replay those values on the peer
- check your .inputrc is the same on the peer
- run xmodmap on local and remote to compare